# Why is a closed ball compact in $C^1[0, 1]\cap L^1[0,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Why is $X=\{f\in C^1[0, 1]:\int^1_0|f(t)|dt\le1\} $ compact in $C^1[0, 1]\cap L^1[0,1]$?

Comment: I am really pissed, man! You set up another question that was highly related to this topic here. I thought more than an hour about it, spent another 10 mins to write my answer and then you deleted it. Very bad behaviour. Very bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C^1[0,1] \subseteq L^1[0,1]$ so $C^1[0, 1]\cap L^1[0,1] = C^1[0, 1]$.

So the question is whether $X$ is compact in $(C^1[0,1],\|\cdot\|_1)$.

The answer is no.

Let $e_1 \in X$ be any function. Define $M_1 = \mathrm{span}\,\{e_1\}$. Since $M$ is finite-dimensional, $M$ is a proper closed subspace of $C^1[0,1]$ so using the [Riesz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma), there exists $e_2 \in C^1[0,1]$ such that $\|e_2\|_1 = 1$, and $\|e_2 - v\|_1 \ge 1, \forall v \in M_1$. This implies $e_2 \in X$, $\|e_2 - e_1\| \ge 1$.

Now define $M_2 = \mathrm{span}\,\{e_1, e_2\}$. $M_2$ is again finite-dimensional so it is a proper closed subspace of $C^1[0,1]$. Using Riesz lemma, there exists $e_3 \in X$ such that $\|e_3 - e_1\| \ge 1$, $\|e_3 - e_2\| \ge 1$.

Continuing this procedure, we obtain a sequence $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $X$ without a convergent subsequence (we have $\|e_m - e_n\| \ge 1$ for any $m \ne n$ so there does not exists a subsequence which is Cauchy).

Hence, $X$ is not compact.